# Flagging "not an answer"

Tags: discussion, answers, policy, flagging

Now that I have more than 10k rep I get notices from the system to agree/disagree to some flags. There is this answer flagged as "no an answer" https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58895 but I disagree. What do you feel: would you flag that as "no an answer"?

Comment: I regularly flag answers as "not an answer", but I wouldn't have flagged this. It's borderline to "ought to be a comment" though, and it seems someone has converted it to a comment. I guess the rule-of-thumb goes something like: Just mentioning a package should be a comment, showing how to use a package is an answer.

Comment: @doncherry This particular answer just tells "try `tabu`" without any pointer to how this package could solve the problem (and I doubt it can). Very short answers tend to be in "ought-to-be-a-comment" category (but it's not a general rule).

Comment: Agree with both: I converted to a comment here for more or less the reasons @egreg gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not flagged this as "not an answer" because it was not clear to me. Turning this into a comment is however a good idea, so next time I will flag an answer like this one.

Answer (score 5):

There also seems a trend to flag incorrect answers as “not an answer”. Please don't do that. Just downvote or add a comment.

E.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59229/83 *is* an answer. It just doesn't do what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The linked post is an attempt to answer the question so the "not an answer" flag does not apply to it according to its description *"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question."*. Please flag it as "low quality" if you really think it needs to converted to a comment by a moderator and not be the OP himself.