# Flagging obviously wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, flagging

Simple question: Should we flag answers that are obviously not answering the question? I don't mean the cases of "question in answer" or "comment in answer", I really mean when question is about X and answer answers Y, where X and Y are completely different.

*(Remark: Some comment treating this is in [this meta post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2533/flagging-not-an-answer) but it is about one specific case.)*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would leave a comment on the answer, explaining why it doesn't answer the question, giving the poster the chance to respond and argue their point/adjust their answer/remove it. If after that you still think the answer is wrong and might be misleading for others, downvote it. That's what the voting system is for. I don't think flagging is the right thing to do in this case.

Comment: +1, but: While you’re under a certain rep threshold, you can flag for *very low quality*: “This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.” I think this would be appropriate if available.

Comment: @doncherry: Fair enough, I didn't think of that. So my point of view only holds for high-rep users (whatever the threshold to "high-rep" may be).

Comment: Please, explain me then why one recent post got 4 "not an answer" flags already, it falls exactly in this category (I'm not sure if I want to post a link, I think everyone with 10k+ can find it in Tools)

Comment: @tohecz: Why (and how) should I explain to you why four people did something that is not in line with what I would do?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it somehow rhetorically and just stated it badly, my excuses.

Answer (score 5):

Emphasis mine:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   **or deleted altogether**.

So **yes**: If you think that the answer is so horribly wrong that it should be deleted - flag it.

Comment: I don’t think these are the cases tohecz is asking about. The flag you’re quoting I use for answers that the OP, if he or she had known better about our Q&A format, had not posted as an answer. If I understand correctly, however, tohecz is asking about cases in which the answerer is misguided in terms of the content of their answer, i.e. the post is an answer (according to our Q&A format), but it is wrong contentwise, possibly because the answerer didn’t understand the question fully.